# Center VBox in Pane

Tags: javafx-8, fxml, centering, pane

I new to javaFx and using fxml to create templates.
I can't manage to center a `Vbox` in a `Pane` that is too big, although I'm certain it must be quite straightforward.
I also want a border around the `VBox`.

Can anyone help? Here is what I have:

```xml
<TitledPane text="Title" collapsible="false">
     <content>
        <GridPane hgap="10" vgap="10">
           <children>
              <VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" spacing="10">
                  <!-- Content -->
              </VBox>
           </children>
           <columnConstraints>
              <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER"/>
           </columnConstraints>
           <rowConstraints>
              <RowConstraints/>
           </rowConstraints>
        </GridPane>
     </content>
  </TitledPane>
```

I guess the `GridPane` is a bad idea, but this is the way I know to have the borders as I want them.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess the `GridPane` is a bad idea, but this is the way I know to have the borders as I want them.

Yes it is. Using a `GridPane` for a single child is a overkill. Simply use a `StackPane` with a `padding` of `10`:

```xml
<TitledPane text="Title" collapsible="false">
    <content>
        <StackPane>
            <padding>
                <Insets topRightBottomLeft="10"/>
            </padding>
            <children>
                <VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" spacing="10">
                    <children>
                        <!-- Content -->
                    </children>
                </VBox>
            </children>
        </StackPane>
    </content>
</TitledPane>
```

Comment: That did the trick for the padding (had to separate top, right, bottom and left though), but now the tables (TableView to be exact) contained in the Vbox take the whole width (before they were only taking about 3/5th of the space and were all the way to the left). How can I center them ?

Comment: @ldebroux Set [`fillWidth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html#fillWidthProperty) to `false` for the `VBox`.